# How to pass the list elements present within map in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm currently learning scala-spark so please bear with me.

I'm trying to apply a function to scala dataframe to create a new column as below -

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

object DatasetName extends Enumeration {
    type DatasetNameType = Value
    val XYZ: DatasetName.Value = Value("xyz")
}

object CommonEntity {
    object Fields {
        val YEAR_COL = "year"
        val MONTH_COL = "month"
    }
}

object Mappings {
    
import DatasetName._
import CommonEntity._

val PERIOD_MAPPING: Map[DatasetName.Value, List[String]] = Map(
  XYZ -> List(CommonEntity.Fields.YEAR_COL, CommonEntity.Fields.MONTH_COL)
)
    
}

def withPeriod(datasetName: DatasetName.Value): DataFrame = {
      if (Mappings.PERIOD_MAPPING.contains(datasetName)) {
        val columnList = Mappings.PERIOD_MAPPING(datasetName)
        val yearCol =  columnList.apply(0)
        val monthCol = columnList.apply(1)
          
        df.withColumn("period", concat(col(yearCol),col(monthCol)))
          
      }
    else df
```

So, when I run `df.withPeriod(DatasetName.XYZ)` this gives error as below -

```
<console>:163: error: value withPeriod is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

However, it works with `withPeriod(DatasetName.XYZ).show()`

So, I'm bit confused. Please help.

Below is my input dataset

```
val df = Seq(("2023", "Jul"), ("2022", "Dec")).toDF("year", "month")
```

Comment: withPeriod is not a member function of Dataset<Row> (DataFrame) it's one you defined.  I would suggest following [a tour of scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html) / doing a course in Scala to understand why these things are different.  Trying to use Spark without having this basis understanding will likely not be fun.

Comment: can you please complete code and expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to call a method of yours on an existing type like `df.withPeriod(...)`, you need to define what is called an **extension method**.

In Scala 2, this is achieved with the definition of an **implicit class** like following:

```scala
object DataframeExtensions {

  implicit class DataframePeriodExtension(df: Dataframe) {
    def withPeriod(...) = {
      // You can refer to df here 
      ???
    }
  }

}
```

And use it like this:

```scala
import DataframeExtensions._

val someDataframe: Dataframe = ???

someDataframe.withPeriod(...)
```

Note that this is just for convenience. Having a plain old method and calling `withPeriod(df, ...)` is exactly the same.